# Custom basket icon with count for android application

Tags: android, cart

I am developing a sample ordering application. I want show basket icon with added item count. So whenever user add the item to the cart, the count in basket icon should increment.

I want to show like this image in the bottom of application screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use FrameLayout

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/counter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/basket"
    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/spacing_small" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/counter_value"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="1"
    android:gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```

text colour of TextView should match the background.
Then use java(activity) to increment the counter value.

Comment: Thank all of u for giving reply to this question. I found the solution. I set the text view background as image. <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lblCartCount"
        android:background="@drawable/shopping_bag_icon"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="4"/>

Answer (score 0):

Create a button. Choose a background image and textcolor so that your number can be seen over the background. And get the value of cart and set it as text for button in your java class.

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:background="@drawable/Your_Background"
android:gravity="center"
android:textColor="#000000"  // use your preferred color    
/>
```

then in java classe do

```
mybutton=(Button) findviewById(R.id.button);
```

Whenever number incremented do

```
 mybutton.setText(""+number+"")
```

Comment: Thank all of u for giving reply to this question. I found the solution. I set the text view background as image. <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lblCartCount"
        android:background="@drawable/shopping_bag_icon"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="4"/>

Comment: U should accept an answer that works for you so that people can get haelp later on. You can also post your own answer